# In a LightSwitch HTML Client project, should ModelManifest.xml files be stored in repository?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

In a LightSwitch HTML Client project, the ModelManifest.xml files present on the Server and HTMLClient directories seem to change every time the solution is opened. This causes merge conflicts if two developers work on the same project.
Should the ModelManifest.xml files be stored in the source control repository?

What these files are used for? What would be the consequences of not versioning them?

I searched the MSDN forum ([1], [2]) and a community member claims these files are not needed in source control, but no clarification is given.

[1] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/36f38eb0-fc64-4050-8d67-f7fb39c2ad4e

[2] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/594aab9f-36c7-4e75-bb9d-07a3a0b0e3ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on the [LightSwitch HTML Client Preview Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchhtml/thread/fef79c6c-8aea-4959-9a0e-f5c793f67bb8/) by PiersonLee, Microsoft Employee, LightSwitch:

"They are generated when the project loads the model files. Because it's generated each time the project loads, these files don't need to be added to source control."